# Proper Syntax for Writing Multiple Fields with odbc_func?

Tags: mysql, asterisk

This is a follow-up to my previous post.  Trying to write to the CDR table on hangup.  Asterisk 13 seems to prevent using the CDR() in the h extension (though I could in *11).
SO, I will just create a nice ODBC_FUNC function and use that to write my data.
Except I can't make it work.
I want to write multiple fields:

```
 exten => h,n,Set(ODBC_WRITE_TEST(${E})=First\,Second,Third,Fourth)
```

or

```
 exten => h,n,Set(ODBC_WRITE_TEST(${E})=${cause_name},${cause_name}, ${TrNumber},${uID})
```

Neither of these work.  They both write a blank record to the table so we know what ODBC is working.  But the field content does not get passed.
func_odbc.conf:

```
 [WRITE_TEST]
 dsn=asterisk
 ; writesql=INSERT INTO LogAndDebug (debugMessage, debugData, logMessage) VALUES ('test','123','done')
 writesql=INSERT INTO LogAndDebug (debugMessage, debugData, logMessage) VALUES ('${SQL_ESC(${ARG1})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAR2})}','${SQL_ESC(${VAR1})}')
```

The commented line above does write data as expected.  The uncommend line writes an empty record.

I have tried it without the SQL_ESC.  The fields are varchars...so quoted text seems correct.  It looks as if the ARGx and VARx are not being passed.

I have looked for documentation on this in Asterisk docs, and surprise -- NADA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of asterisk 1.8 func_odbc is like that:

In func_odbc.conf:

```
[WRITE_TEST]
dsn=asterisk
writesql=INSERT INTO LogAndDebug (debugMessage, debugData, logMessage) VALUES ('${ARG1}','${VAR2}','${VAR3}')
```

In dialplan:

```
exten => s,n,NoOp(WRITE_TEST.${ODBC_WRITE_TEST('this','is','test')})
```

Comment: Update. Missed mandatory "ODBC_" prefix in call of odbc-function in dialplan.